# Weakest assumptions for central limit theorem to hold?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, assumptions, central-limit-theorem

Let $X_i$, $i=1,2,...$ be any sequence of random variables (i.e. not necessarily independent or identically distributed).  What are some weak conditions you know of on $X_i$ that makes $\sum_i X_i$, or some other R.V. related to the sum (e.g. multiplied by $1/\sqrt{n}$, by $1/n$) approach a gaussian-distributed R.V.?

Comment: If the variables are independent, the weakeast assumptions are the Lindeberg conditions (which limits how different the variances can be). If the variables can be dependent, I don't know, so others maybe?

Comment: A couple of useful places to look: 1. Wikipedia on the various forms of [CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem). 2. Terry Tao has written about [forms of CLT and related theorems, and methods of proof](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/central-limit-theorem/) in his blog a couple of times (based on class notes by the look). There's a few things that may be of interest there.